# diffrent style for post single page

Tags: single

We need to style a single page differently depending on what user journey you take. Currently we have event posts listed in WP, they are either under the "get involved > events" page or "urban innovation center > attend an event" some events are listed in both. If you come from "get involved > events" we need the single event page to have a light background and if you come from "urban innovation center > attend an event" we need the single event page to have a dark background. We dont want to have to duplicate the events in WP.

https://futurecities.catapult.org.uk/events/

Comment: @jdm2112 not really sure where to start with this?

Answer (score 1):

You could listen for the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` and add a class to the body depending on that referer

```
add_filter( 'body_class','wpse_body_classes' );
function wpse_body_classes( $classes ) { 

  if ( is_page( 'event' ) ){ // event is the page slug of the page we wish to add the class for


    if( wp_get_referer() == '/url/of/get_involved' ){

      $classes[] = 'my-light-bg';

    }

    elseif( wp_get_referer() == '/url/of/urban_innovation_center' ){

      $classes[] = 'my-dark-bg';

    }

    else {

      $classes[] = 'my-default-bg';

    }    

  }

  return $classes;

}
```

**EDIT**

Updated the code to

- make use of [wp_get_referer](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_referer)
- check if we are on the *event* page so the filter only runs on that page
- add a default body class to that page if no referrer is set

Comment: WP has a function for this: [wp_get_referer](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_referer).

Comment: Also you'd need a default - in case someone is coming from a search engine or a bookmark.

Comment: @vancoder good comment, I wasn't aware of that function. updated the answer to reflect this

Comment: A problem you might have is that, as no useful referer will be available when someone visits from Google, your page will have to "guess" what colour to show in that case.

Comment: I think my update takes care of that now. I think a `switch/case` could also be used here and set a default case to take care of that issue.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping in mind the issues with checking referers, I'd probably approach this differently.

I'd append a parameter to the permalink using [add_query_arg](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/). The param added would be different for each referring page - eg, `get involved > events` might add `class=my-light-bg`, whereas `urban innovation center > attend an event` might add `class=my-dark-bg`.

Your event page itself could then retrieve that parameter by looking at $_GET[ 'class' ].

The advantage here is that, even when coming from a bookmark or search engine result, the correct style will be presented.